# Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace when defining package

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have 3 XSD's in my project. Two in the namespace "A" and one in namespace "B".

I want to generate XSD-1, XSD-2 (same namespace) into one package.
Then generate XSD-3 in to an different package.

I am trying to do this via the bindings.xjb file.

If I declare

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd1-namespaceA.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.xsdPrimary" />       
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd2-namespaceA.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.xsdPrimary" />               
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd3-namespaceB.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.xsdSecondary" />             
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Then I get the error:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target 
namespace "http://www.jeff-test.org/namespaceA/"
```

If I remove the first two entries in the bindings file, then the generation works, but it puts all my classes in a package called "jeff-test.namespaceA" for namespaceA and all those from namespaceB in the package "com.xsdSecondary".

I want all the classes from namespace-A into one package and all those from namespace-B into another package.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Multiple  are defined for the target namespace "http://www.jeff-test.org/namespaceA/"
>
> If I remove the first two entries in the bindings file, then the generation works, but it puts all my classes in a package called "jeff-test.namespaceA" for namespaceA...

Just remove just one of the entries for `namespaceA`. What's the logic behind removing both?

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd1-namespaceA.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.xsdPrimary" />       
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd3-namespaceB.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="com.xsdSecondary" />             
    </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

`schemaBindings` is considered once per namespace, it does not matter which schema file is it bound to (as long as this file is a part of the compilation).

Comment: Logic, this was just to prove that its is possible to generate the classes of the same namespace in to a single package.  (I'll update my question)